# Open Form2 from Form1, How to close Form2, Form1 not close(still showing)?

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I have 1 controller of form 1 : **`ControllerForm1.cs`** to call form 1 display

```
private Form1 frm1 { get; set; }

this.frm1 = new Form1(this);
this.frm1.ShowDialog();
```

In the **`form1 (Form1.cs)`** is a button , when I click it, then open the **`form2 (Form2.cs)`** and **form1 not close(still showing)**

```
private Form2 frm2 { get; set; }

private void btnForm1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int num = Calculate();
    if (num != 0)
        {
            // Show form 2
            this.frm2 = new Form2(this);
            this.frm2.ShowDialog();
        }
        else
        {
            this.Close();
        }
}
```

**`Form 2(Form2.cs)`** is a Close button

```
private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}
```

I dont know how to do, if I close Form2, Form1 not close(still showing).

I've tried to do, but when click the button close of the form 2, form 1 is closed.

Comment: Do not use `.ShowDialog()` to your `Form2`

Comment: If you want to close `Form1`, immediately after closing `Form2`, it's enough to call `this.Close();` after `frm2.ShowDialog();`. What's the problem?

Comment: I used .ShowDialog() to Form2, because when form 2 is displayed, I dont want to manipulation on form 1

Comment: Reza: I dont want to close Form1, after closing Form2. 
I want when form2 close, form1 not close(still showing)

Comment: @MinhKiyo `Form1` is still open. You  didn't close it.

Comment: Between your post and your comments, I can't quite figure out what the problem is.  The code you posted does not make Form1 close when you close Form2.  You contradict yourself in what the problem is.  What is currently happening, and what *should* happen instead?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I would rethink.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Form2 frm= new Form2();
 frm.Show();
 frm.Focus();
 this.Hide();
```

Comment: I dont want to close Form1, after closing Form2 . How to do ?

Comment: you can also reopen